# Download excel file before query in fully completed

Tags: reactjs, export-to-excel

I am used library [`react-data-export`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-export).

My problem is that I created the excel file before finishing the query, now I have to press twice to make it work

Code:

```
import ReactExport from "react-data-export";
const ExcelFile = ReactExport.ExcelFile;
const ExcelSheet = ReactExport.ExcelFile.ExcelSheet;
import axios from 'axios';

class Main extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            multiDataSet: []
        }
        this.getDataExcel = this.getDataExcel.bind(this);
    }

getDataExcel() {
    let self = this;
    axios.get('/app/webapi/datos/excel'
        ).then(function (response) {
            self.setState({ multiDataSet: response.data});
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}   
render() {
    return (
        <ExcelFile name="excel2" filename="excelDatos" element={<Button label="Exportar" icon="fa fa-file-excel-o" onClick={this.getDataExcel}/>}>
            <ExcelSheet dataSet={this.state.multiDataSet} name="Datos_Excel"/>
        </ExcelFile>

    );
)
```

How to wait for the query to finish to create the excel?

Comment: What does press twice means? double click or second click after some time?

Comment: @UmairFarooq second click after some time

Comment: Please share code in codesandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start fetching the data on component mount (before the download button was clicked), and render the ExcelFile only after the data was fetched. Like so:

```
class Main extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            fetching: true,
            multiDataSet: null,
        }
        this.getDataExcel = this.getDataExcel.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // ********* the data is fetched on component mount, before the download button appears *********
        this.getDataExcel();
    }

    getDataExcel() {
        let self = this;
        axios.get('/app/webapi/datos/excel'
            ).then(function (response) {
                self.setState({ multiDataSet: response.data, fetching: false });
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                self.setState({ fetching: false });
            });
    }   

    render() {
        const { fetching, multiDataSet } = this.state;
        if (fetching) return <div>Loading...</div>;
        if (!multiDataSet) return <div>Failed to fetch data</div>;

        return (
            // ********* notice I removed the onClick event from the button *********
            <ExcelFile name="excel2" filename="excelDatos" element={<Button label="Exportar" icon="fa fa-file-excel-o"/>}>
                <ExcelSheet dataSet={this.state.multiDataSet} name="Datos_Excel"/>
            </ExcelFile>
        );
    }
}
```